# In Perl, how can I convert an array of bytes to a Unicode string?

Tags: perl, utf-8, arrays

Does anyone knows how to do this? Is this even possible?

I've read about decode and encode but since I'm not an expert I don't know if it will help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course, it is possible. If you have the byte array

```
my @bytes = (0xce, 0xb1, 0xce, 0xb2, 0xce, 0xb3);
```

you need to first combine those into a string of octets:

```
my $x = join '', map chr, @bytes;
```

Then, you can use [utf8::decode](https://metacpan.org/pod/utf8#Utility-functions) to convert that to UTF-8 *in place*:

```
utf8::decode($x)
    or die "Failed to decode UTF-8";
```

You can also use [Encode::decode_utf8](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode#decode_utf8).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.020; # why not?!
use strict;
use warnings;

use Encode qw( decode_utf8 );
use open qw(:std :utf8);

my @bytes = (0xce, 0xb1, 0xce, 0xb2, 0xce, 0xb3);
my $x = join '', map chr, @bytes;

say "Using Encode::decode_utf8";
say decode_utf8($x);

utf8::decode($x)
    or die "Failed to decode in place";

say "Using utf8::decode";
say $x;
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> perl tt.pl  
Using Encode::decode_utf8                      
αβγ                                            
Using utf8::decode                             
αβγ
```

`Encode` allows you to convert among many character encodings. Its functions allow you to specify what happens in case the [encoding/decoding operations fail](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode#Handling-Malformed-Data) whereas with `utf8::decode` you are limited to explicitly checking success/failure.